# Formatting html dates and numbers on the fly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

i have some html like so:

```
    <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("Num") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("myDate") %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I apply formatting to the first value like:
DataFormatString="{0:f4}
and to the date like:
DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}

I usually use a dataGrid where I can use the above properties in the BoundColumn section but i'm not sure how to use the same formatting when I try it as above

Answer (score 4):

You can include the formatting as a parameter of the Eval function:

```
<td><%# Eval("Num","{0:f4}") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("myDate","{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
<td><%# ((DateTime)Eval("myDate")).ToString("{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %></td>
```